# Angularjs after modifying the body of the page functions no longer work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After try printing a specific area of the page. the functions stop working after print is close.

Can anyone help?

```
$scope.printContent = function(){
     var restorePage = $(document.body).html();
     var printContent = $('#PrintArea').html();

     $(document.body).html(printContent);
     window.print();
     $(document.body).html(restorePage);
};
```

Comment: Add fiddle of your code...

Comment: You probably need to recompile your application. Please add more code in plunker for example.